# character class: eager negative or lazy posative?

Tags: regex

If I want to capture everything up to a terminus, I believe these two return equivalent results.

```
([^=]+)=
(.+?)=
```

Other than your code golf score, is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: `.` does not always match line break chars by default, `[^=]` almost always does it (except in Vim). Besides, `.` can match `=` and `(.+?)=` will match `==` in `==text` and `([^=]+)=` will not find a match in that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negated character class pattern will match its content in a single step, while the lazy one will expand character by character, which should make the former perform better.

Take care concerning line breaks, `.` might or might not involve the line break character depending on engine and modifiers, [^=] will involve it in almost all engines.

If there is further stuff following in the pattern, `.+?` might expand over border characters while `[^=]+` will never. E.g. `([^=]+)=3` and `(.+?)=3` will match differently on `1=2=3`.